# When connecting UTP cable to WiFi extender to extend router's wifi, I cannot access internet through router's wifi anymore

Tags: wireless-extender

I'm using Netgear wrn2000 extender and Asus RT-N12+ router.

I added extender to an existing wifi network (Asus router) and it works fine. But now I want to connect UTP cable from router to the extender, so the extended signal will be better. Of course, I could use another router, but I don't have another one.

When extender is receiving wifi and extending it, I can connect with my laptop to either extender or router. Both work fine and I can access the internet through any of them. But the problem appears when I connect UTP cable into extender: I can still successfully connect to extender with my computer and internet works great, but there is no internet access when connecting to router with my laptop.

When I disconnect cable from extender, both of them have access to internet again.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I happen to have one of those units. Looking through all of the manuals, the device is not exactly designed to be used as a wireless access point in the sense of hard-wiring ethernet into it and getting wifi out. Its only access port that is designed to connect to your router is the wifi. What is likely happening is that you have created a situation where the ethernet packets are traveling around your network in circles such that it eventually eats up all your available network bandwidth as follows:

A device sends out a broadcast message to all the other devices on the network, for example something called ARP, which essentially says "I want to talk to computer X, what is your MAC address?" The router dutifully sends this out all ports, including the wifi port, except for the port from which it received the request. Your wifi extender receives this request over wifi. It dutifully sends out the request over all ports (the wifi extender network and all hardwired ethernet ports) except for the port from which it came (the primary wifi network), including the port connected directly back to the router. The router receives the request, not remembering it just sent this out to the network, and forwards it to all ports (wired and wifi) except the wired port from which it came.

Your wifi extender then receives the packet again, forwards it, and the cycle keeps repeating.

There are ways to connect networks together through redundant connections like you did, but using consumer-grade hardware like this is not one of them. The proper solutions to this particular issue would be to connect an access point with the ethernet cable or use the extender as designed and only connect it to your network with wifi. With enterprise-grade gear, you could set up multiple connections with multiple routers linked together, but even that can have some problems if not properly configured.

In short, do not connect the UTP (or even STP Cat 7) from your router to the extender while the wifi connection is enabled, but disabling the wifi connection pretty much turns the extender into a very expensive 3-port switch (one port to link to the router, three other ports). And even for that application you may need a crossover cable since essentially you are connecting a switch (one of multiple switched ports on the router) to a switch (one of the switched ports on the extender). I don't know if these units are capable of auto-negotiating using a regular cable.

Comment: This really must be it. At least now I'll know where the problem lies and stop wasting time figuring out what is wrong. Thank you!